# SOQL Child fields Join

Tags: soql, query

I have a query and I need to do a subQuery on it, I have tryed everything but I don't find the way to make it work.

```
select id, 
    Name,
    parentField__c,
    (Select id, name, Childfield__c
        from ChildObject__c)

    from ParentObject__c
    where ParentObject__c = :varToFilter
```

The error is:

> Didn't understand relationship 'ChildObject__c' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

What should I do to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, the relationship is plural, and a custom relationship will alway end in `__r`. Try:

```
(SELECT Name FROM ChildObjects__r)
```

You can always get the verbatim name via this `Execute Anonymous` script:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.ParentObject__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject()() == ChildObject.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

Whatever this script spits out, put in place of `ChildObjects__r`.

Comment: A child relationship name ends in `__r` in most situations, but not in _all_ situations (i.e. not for standard relationships). Consider `[SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account]`.

Comment: I personally feel the easy way to get child relationship names is via workbench.

Comment: It's another route. You can get the describes however you wish, but the point is that's where you need to look. Workbench requires a separate login so usually I don't go that route (especially since I normally have the Dev Console open anyway).